# How to compare two text files and print the differences in python?

Tags: python, compare, text-files

I need to take two text files and compare them to see if they are the same or different. If they are the same then it will output "Yes" and if they are different it will output "No". It also will print out the differences between the two text files. For example if one text file has this:

- Hello world!
- abc

And the other text file has this:

- Hello world!
- xyz

Then the output would be:

- No
- abc
- xyz

```
firstFile = input("Enter the first file name: ")
secondFile = input("Enter the second file name: ")

f1 = open(firstFile,'r')
f2 = open(secondFile,'r')
i = 0

for line1 in f1:
    i += 1
      
    for line2 in f2:
          
        # matching line1 from both files
        if line1 == line2:  
            # print IDENTICAL if similar
            print("Yes")       
        else:
            print("Line ", i, ":")
            # else print that line from both files
            print("\tFile 1:", line1, end='')
            print("\tFile 2:", line2, end='')
```

Comment: Instructions say output should be 'No' if lines are identical but code above outputs "Yes" and comment says print "IDENTICAL". Please clarify the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over 2 files sequentially and compare each line then you can use `readLine()` on both files inside a single loop. This will compare exact matches on a given line.

You may or may not want to consider what to do if one file has fewer lines than the other.

You can do something like this:

```python
with open(firstFile, "r") as f1, open(secondFile, "r") as f2:
    line = 0
    while True:
        line += 1
        s1 = f1.readline()
        s2 = f2.readline()
        if len(s1) == 0:
            # file1 is at end
            if len(s2) != 0:
                # file2 is not at the end
                print(f"Line {line}:")
                print(s2)
            break
        if len(s2) == 0:
          # file1 has data but file2 is at end
          print(f"Line {line}:")
          print(s2)
          break
        if s1 == s2:
            print("IDENTICAL ")
        else:
            print(f"Line {line}:")
            print(s1, end='')
            print(s2, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `zip` to iterate over two files:

```
with open("test1.txt", "r") as left_file, open("test2.txt", "r") as right_file:
        
    differences = []
    
    for left, right in zip(left_file, right_file):
        
        if left != right:
            differences.append((left.rstrip(), right.rstrip()))
    
    print("No" if differences else "Yes")
    
    for difference in differences:
        
        print(difference[0])
        print(difference[1])
```

---

Something I just learned myself and I like to pass along...

If you only have to compare them if they are identical, then you could use [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html):

```py
is_identical = filecmp.cmp("test1.txt", "test2.txt", shallow=False)
```

Another interesting package is [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html). It allows you to use different diff methods. Below an example for an unified diff:

```py
import difflib

with open("test1.txt", "r") as left, open("test2.txt", "r") as right:
    
    differences = difflib.unified_diff(left.readlines(), right.readlines())
        
    for difference in differences:  # difference is empty if no differences
        print(difference)
```